# Prettier is not working at React project

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

I am migrating my airbnb eslint rules to prettier rules, but I'm having some issues.

Here is my .eslintrc:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": ["prettier", "react"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "singleQuote": true,
        "semi": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "prettier", "prettier/react"]
}
```

With this setup I got these errors at my App.jsx file:

> 'React' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)
>
> 'Header' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './App.scss';
import Header from '../header/Header';

const App = () =>
  <div className={style.wrapper}>
    <Header />
  </div>;

export default App;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to add the [esLint `react` plugin](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react).

```
"extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", ...]
```

This will add the `react/jsx-uses-react` rule which will prevent React from being incorrectly marked as unused when JSX is in use.

Answer (score 15):

steps to follow (using prettier[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM2Fs.png)):

1. Click on the right corner text 'JavaScript React'
2. select configure 'JavaScript React' language based settings
3. add this snippet in the file

```
    "[javascriptreact]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
        },
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
```

All set to run perfect!

Comment: thank you so much!!!!! I had this problem for some time now

Answer (score 11):

Go to settings and type default formatter which is null at the beginning. Change it to esbenp.prettier-vscode.
This is what is working for me. Hope it does for you.

Answer (score 5):

Just install Extension Prettier ESLint [Prettier ESlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint) (make sure you already install Prettier [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) )

After installing the extension change default formatter to Prettier ESlint

Steps for Changing default formatter setting in VSCode

1. ctrl+shift+p to open Preferences
2. Type Format Document with and press enter
3. Select Configure default formatter
4. Now select Prettier eslint

Now whenever you want to Formate the React document just save the file using ctrl+s

Answer (score 0):

choose Default Formatter `Prettier`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you have multiple formatters working press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>,
Type `Format Document` and select the one you want.

Then,
Go to `settings` (Vscode), Search `Format`, and toggle `Format on Save(✔)`.