# brackets space inside not found Prettier

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

My Bracket Spacing is enabled to insert space between my vestments within { param }, but when saved to format it removes {param} the spaces from my parameter. I use the prttier.

Comment: there can be some other conflicting rule or from your editor settings.

Comment: use 2 prettier and beaultfy plugins, but (both) are set to format a specific language

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this one:

[prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) then try `reinstalling` it and `restart` your vs code it will work

Comment: I uninstalled, restarted vscode and installed plugin again, but the error persists

Comment: I have changed the answer hope it helps u buddy please take a look

Comment: I have auso save on. But I tried to use the way you said and it wasn’t

Comment: I use prettier to format my javascriptreact

Comment: my be this can help u out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286299/12147452